# accessing controls in datalist headertemplate from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist in my application whose headertemplate has a lable.Now i need to access the lable from codebehind.How can i do that..

**CODE**:

```
      <asp:DataList ID="Dlitems" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4"
                        CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="15" OnItemCommand="Dlitems_ItemCommand">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                              <asp:Label ID="lblcat" runat="server" Text="" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
```

**NOTE**:I need to access the lable `lblcat` from headertemplate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach `OnItemDataBound` event with your datalist like this

```
<asp:DataList ID="Dlitems" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4"
CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="15" OnItemCommand="Dlitems_ItemCommand" 
OnItemDataBound="Dlitems_ItemDataBound">
...
```

And define it like this

```
protected void Dlitems_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
   {
       Label lblCat = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcat");
       lblCat.Text = "Changed!";

    }    
}
```

Comment: for each item that will be binding to the list but it will go to the if condition only once as ItemType header comes only once

Comment: I am not binding anything here.I just wanna give the text to the label in codebehind depending on some conditions thats it....

Comment: If you are not binding anything with your datalist then what you show in it, what is the need of datalist?

Comment: That's called you are binding your data list. You must be calling DlistItems.Datasource=... and DlistItems.Databind(); methods, which is data binding. I think you haven't done your homework and haven't tried anything

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct however you will need to add post back to the code and define it correctly as the user has not click on any buttons or links so we do not want to display Changed unless the user click on the link or button. The as following does that:

```
protected void dlData_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
            {
                Label lblCat = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcat");
                lblCat.Text = "Changed!";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
   }
```

Happy Programming